# Knockout binding with a handle to templated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Knockout is just great but I'm a little bit confused on how to deal with DOM elements after they are generated. For example I have a collection of users. Each user has an Id:

```
var user = {
   id : 123,
   name : 'testUser',
   age: 45
};
```

Using Knockout I bind my collection of described above data structure with the following html template:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: users">
 <div class='user-wrapper'>
   <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
   <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

and now I want to change background color on user click:

```
$(".user-wrapper").click(function (e) {
   //doesn't work - toggelClass is not a function
   e.target.toggleClass("user-selected"); 
});
```

Once I hit a user target could be different (span or div), I need to make sure that I'm getting the right div. Moreover e.target doesn't work with "not a fucntion" error.

How can I access calling element to toggle the class?
How can I get a user id of that element to access other controls related to that id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [the `click` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) in conjunction with [the `css` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html):

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: users">
 <div class='user-wrapper' data-bind="click: toggleSelected, css: { 'user-selected': isSelected }">
   <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
   <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Note that if you're ever tempted to use jQuery to manipulate DOM while you're using KnockoutJS (or client side MVVM libraries in general): *don't*. If you absolutely must, you probably need a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), much like you'd use a *directive* for DOM manipulation in "that other" mvvm framework.

---

Here's a demo:

```js
var user = {
   id : 123,
   name : 'testUser',
   age: 45
};

var UserVm = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.name = data.name;
  self.age = data.age;
  
  self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
  
  self.toggleSelected = function() {
    self.isSelected(!self.isSelected());
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({ users: [new UserVm(user)] });
```

```css
.user-selected { background-color: red; }
.user-wrapper:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: users">
 <div class='user-wrapper' data-bind="click: toggleSelected, css: { 'user-selected': isSelected }">
   <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
   <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```